# Issue with the combination of overflow and negative margin or negative bottom property

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, margin

I have a little problem with the combination of the CSS property `overflow` and a negative `margin` or a deposition with a negative `bottom`.

Here you have a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jwf43rkr/2/) of the problem.

- `overflow & margin:` places it self over the border of the `ground_box` but not completely and only with higher values
- `margin:` does not even bother to move
- `overflow & bottom:` does move but only shows the supposed result with a higher value
- `bottom:` works ... but I need the `overflow` attribute

In conclusion, I have no idea how to get the box above over the `ground_box` div with `overflow: hidden`.